# Removing remote desktop services role (Windows server 2008 R2) remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

I am looking for a way to remove the Remote Desktop Services server role on Windows server 2008 R2 remotely from a command prompt or power shell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want either the `Remove-WindowsFeature` cmdlet, or `ServerManagerCmd.exe`.

This is [well documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732257.aspx) on TechNet.

Comment: Ok but how I can run these command remotely?

Comment: PowerShell has built in remoting capabilities and `psexec.exe` is the standard tool for remotely executing command line tools on remote computers.